# how can I access a nested array within a json data return?

Tags: jquery, json

This is a very slight rehash of a previous question with an important difference. I have a json data return as follows:

```
{
    "api_id": "89881d38-5657-11e4-a2d1-22000ac5040c",
    "country": "Czech Republic",
    "country_code": 420,
    "country_iso": "CZ",
    "message": {
        "inbound": {
            "rate": "0.00000"
        },
        "outbound": {
            "rate": "0.05900"
        },
        "outbound_networks_list": [
            {
                "group_name": "Czech Republic-Telefonica O2",
                "rate": "0.06800"
            },
            {
                "group_name": "Czech Republic-T-Mobile ",
                "rate": "0.06800"
            },
            {
                "group_name": "Czech Republic-U:fon",
                "rate": "0.05900"
            },
            {
                "group_name": "Czech Republic-Vodafone ",
                "rate": "0.05900"
            }
        ]
    },
    "phone_numbers": {
        "local": {
            "rate": "0.80000"
        },
        "tollfree": {
            "rate": null
        }
    },
    "voice": {
        "inbound": {
            "ip": {
                "rate": "0.00300"
            },
            "local": {
                "rate": "0.00500"
            },
            "tollfree": {
                "rate": null
            }
        },
        "outbound": {
            "ip": {
                "rate": "0.00300"
            },
            "local": {
                "rate": "0.02940"
            },
            "rates": [
                {
                    "prefix": [
                        "420608",
                        "4207040",
                        "4207047",
                        "42077",
                        "420967"
                    ],
                    "rate": "0.02940"
                },
                {
                    "prefix": [
                        "420601",
                        "420602",
                        "420603",
                        "420604",
                        "420605",
                        "420606",
                        "420607",
                        "420702",
                        "420703",
                        "42070300",
                        "420705",
                        "42072",
                        "42073",
                        "42077273",
                        "42079",
                        "42079083",
                        "4207920",
                        "4207921",
                        "4207922",
                        "4207923",
                        "4207924",
                        "4207925",
                        "42079950",
                        "42079951",
                        "420840",
                        "420841",
                        "420842",
                        "420847",
                        "420848",
                        "420849",
                        "42093",
                        "420961",
                        "420962",
                        "420963",
                        "420964",
                        "420965",
                        "420966"
                    ],
                    "rate": "0.03010"
                },
                {
                    "prefix": [
                        "420",
                        "4202"
                    ],
                    "rate": "0.03930"
                }
            ],
            "tollfree": {
                "rate": null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can access "phone_numbers.voice.outbound.local.rate" with this piece of code:

```
$.each( data, function( key, value ) {
  //code omitted for convenience
  txt += '<p>Make calls : '+ round((parseFloat(data.voice.outbound.local.rate * 100) + 3.0),2) +' cents per minute</p>';
 }
```

But when I apply the same logic to the nested array where the "prefix" bits appear I get an undefined error message, so:

```
txt += '<p>Prefix: '+ data.["rates"]["prefix"] +'</p>';
```

returns "undefined", similarly:

```
txt += '<p>Prefix: '+ data.rates.prefix +'</p>';
```

also fails. I would like to be able to access that part of the json return and iterate through each of the prefix numbers and print the rate next to it. So we have, for example:

```
<div>
  <p> Prefix: 420608 Rate: 0.02940 </p>
</div>
```

As always, all help gratefully received. Thank you.

Comment: You don't put `.` before `[`. It's either `data.rates` or `data["rates"]`.

Comment: Although that would be a syntax error and not the reported outcome..

Comment: `data.rates[0].prefix` might get somewhere (note that rates is an *array* of objects)

Comment: Anyway, once you have the JSON loaded up into a JS object, navigate through it *using the console*. The failing to correctly navigate / identify the structure is far too localized (and is a typo for my concern).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `data.voice.outbound.rates`. Since that's an array of objects, you need to iterate over it. And then `prefix` is also an array, so you need a nested loop for that:

```
$.each(data.voice.outbound.rates, function(i, prefix_rate) {
    var rate = prefix_rate.rate;
    $.each(prefix_rate.prefix, function(j, prefix) {
        txt += '<p>Prefix: ' + prefix + ' Rate: ' + rate + '</p>';
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks but I still get an error:TypeError: this.outbound_networks_list is undefined

Comment: `outbound_networks_list` isn't in my answer, so I don't know where that's coming from.

Comment: Genius, scholar and gentleman. THANK YOU, I am very grateful it works perfectly!

Comment: You work at BBO. Cool I love BBO and use it most days. Thank you for that too.

Comment: Thank you, I'm glad you enjoy it.